# Remove container on mobile view

Tags: bootstrap-4

We have a image carousel in a container.  On mobile view we want to remove the container so we have full wide image carousel.

How can we do that?

Thanks

remco

Comment: Can you please add any screen short?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use media query and overwrite margins for small screens only.

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .image-container {
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```